# What is in the error in this SQLite statement?

Tags: sql, sqlite, create-table

I got this error:
`SQL error (near "(": syntax error)`

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS demo
(
    code varchar(200) default substr(lower(hex(randomblob(32))),1,6) not null primary key
);
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `DEFAULT` with an expression instead of a literal value, it has to be enclosed in parentheses.

```
DEFAULT (substr(...))
```

From [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html):

> The DEFAULT clause specifies a default value to use for the column if no value is explicitly provided by the user when doing an INSERT. If there is no explicit DEFAULT clause attached to a column definition, then the default value of the column is NULL. An explicit DEFAULT clause may specify that the default value is NULL, a string constant, a blob constant, a signed-number, **or any constant expression enclosed in parentheses**. A default value may also be one of the special case-independent keywords CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_DATE or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. For the purposes of the DEFAULT clause, an expression is considered constant if it contains no sub-queries, column or table references, bound parameters, or string literals enclosed in double-quotes instead of single-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting not null before setting default value:

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS demo ( code varchar(200) primary key not null default substr(lower(hex(randomblob(32))),1,6)   );
```